# Reconfiguring Ext.tree.Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to reconfigure an existing tree. The columns are updated, but the store/data doesn't.

```
handler: function() {        
    var newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        fields: [ 'C4', 'C5', 'C6' ],
        root: {
            text: '.',
            children: [
                { 'C4': 4, 'C5': 5, 'C6': 6 },
                { 'C4': 4, 'C5': 5, 'C6': 6 },
                { 'C4': 4, 'C5': 5, 'C6': 6 },
                { 'C4': 4, 'C5': 5, 'C6': 6 }
            ]
        }
    });

    var newCols = [
        { text: 'C4', dataIndex: 'C4' },
        { text: 'C5', dataIndex: 'C4' },
        { text: 'C6', dataIndex: 'C4' }
    ];

    tree.reconfigure(newStore, newCols);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fR3z3/2/

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree doesn't update it's root node. After calling `tree.reconfigure` I have to call

```
newStore.setRootNode(newStore.getRootNode());
```

And now it works.

Next problem, if I add new cols, the data of these cols would not be bound to the tree grid. I have to define a new Model.

Here is the full working example

http://jsfiddle.net/kleines0eichhoernchen/fR3z3/3/